# Hook into WordPress update?

Tags: hooks, updates, automatic-updates, http-api

I'd like to know if there's any way to hook into WordPress update process and send `$_POST` variable to update server?

I'm delivering plugin/theme updates from private server and I hook into this:

`add_filter('pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', 'check_for_update');`

which works just fine. Newer version of theme/plugin appears under Dashboard > Updates and I can update. But the problem is - I want users to only be able to download/update if they provided correct login/password (first via `add_option()`). Ideally, direct link should never work unless client sends `$_POST` with login/password to update.php (the files on update server that will send plugin.ZIP in return).

I'm looking for something like this:

```
add_filter('updating', 'my_func');
function my_func($request){
   $request['login'] = get_option('login');
   $request['pass'] = get_option('pass');
   return $request;
}
```

And WordPress, while updating theme/plugin, should send `$_POST['login']` and `$_POST['pass']` to http://example.com/update.php and update.php should only allow downloading/updating if login matches the one defined there (update.php is the file on update server that sends ZIP package with newer plugin to WordPress).

I hope that it's clear :)

Comment: Did you change update url in WP? How?

Comment: Check my hook above and use `function check_for_update($checked_data) { return $checked_data; }` - you can add more themes/plugins to `$checked_data` and they can come from private servers. I also managed to resolve this issue already in a bit different way :) There are tutorials out there on that subject and they are of great help here.

Comment: did you finished the code for it? if so, are you willing to share it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update & the internal WP HTTP API

A slightly modified version of [my answer to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77981/upgrade-network-error-stuck-with-ssl-certificate-verification/77982), but also as a plugin that shows how it **could** work.

Note: The code is not tested - I don't know your server setup, etc. - and just written out of my head. You'll have to test it, find the proper position for merging the arguments and set your URL, etc.

The initial test (#1) could be improved if the custom remote repository sends back usable headers (which isn't often the case). So if it does, you're better off using [`wp_remote_head()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_remote_head/) instead as it makes the HTTP request more lightweight.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#78267) Custom Theme Update Args
 * Description: Adds custom arguments to the HTTP request for a theme or plugin update from a custom location.
 * Version:     2013-04-02.2139
 * Author:      Franz Josef Kaiser <wecodemore@gmail.com>
 * Author URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 * License:     The MIT License (MIT)
 * LicenseURI:  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

add_filter( 'http_request_args', 'custom_upgrade_process', 9, 2 );
/**
 * Callback for a HTTP request used to switch the
 * SSL verification in case of a WP error response
 * and routing to a custom Theme or Plugin repository.
 * @param  array  $r   Request arguments
 * @param  string $url Request URL
 * @return array  $r
 */
function custom_upgrade_process( $r, $url )
{
    // Alter the following settings according to your
    // update procedure and admin pages that deliver it.
    # A) The admin URL
    $custom_repo = 'https://example.com?foo=bar';

    if (
        0 !== strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check' )
        XOR 0 !== strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/themes/update-check' )
    )
        return $r;

    # 1) Do an initial test to check if things are working as expected
    $response = wp_remote_get(
        $custom_repo,
        array(
            'timeout'     => 120,
            'httpversion' => '1.1',
        )
    );
    # 2) Turn off SSL verification in case the HTTP request didn't work out
    if (
        is_wp_error( $response )
        AND strstr( $response->get_error_message(), 'SSL: certificate subject name' )
    )
        add_filter( 'https_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );

    # 3) Add your custom request arguments
    $r = array_merge( $r, array(
        'login' => get_option( 'login' ),
        'pass'  => get_option( 'pass' ),
    ) );

    return $r;
}
```

Good luck. :)